# Orchard Can I query based on url or page ID from a projector widget?

Tags: url, widget, orchardcms, projector

I would like to know if I can create a query for a projector widget which filters a content type with a certain tag if it is on a certain page (by url or id)? So if on Page1 show Items tagged with Tag1, if Page2 show Items tagged with Tag2 etc...? I have been trying for a while and can't seem to get anywhere.

I have 3 content types, called 'Products', which are shown on a projection page. Each product has it's own page which has a projector widget which queries to show content types called 'Features', which are tagged accordingly. e.g. home/products/Product1 should show just the 'Features' that are tagged 'prod1'.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how and if not, is there a (better) alternative? I know I can do this with layers but I have too many products to have to produce a layer per product.

I would really appreciate an answer as I've been stuck on this for 2 days now!

Thank you

Comment: I would like to know this too. I'm working on a solution, but at the moment my biggest issue is that I can't include and id in the query or it crashes

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a token which gives you currently displayed product. Then you can write a custom filter for your projection widget. Inside Filter you can filter the 'Features' which are tagged with token (currently displayed product.).

you should watch video on projections by Bertrand Le Roy for better understanding of projections. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka55wTTXZg8